# GNOME Freezes Unless I Use Weird .xinitrc

Tags: linux, gnome, xvfb

Here's one for you - let's see if any Linux gods out there can explain this one.

I am trying to start gnome-session on a Xvfb. I use

```
startx -- `which Xvfb` :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

And in the .xinitrc file, I have at the end

```
exec gnome-session
```

When I connect to the x11vnc, I can see the desktop. Hovering the mouse over the date and time 'appears' to indent ready to be clicked. But much past that - everything is frozen up. A few mouse clicks, and I get the 'watch' cursor. OK, now I change my .xinitrc to something like this;

```
gnome-session &
exec xclock
```

GNOME happily runs - as long as I keep xclock open (otherwise shutting this will obviously shut down the Xserver).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. The `.xinitrc` script exits when the session exits. So `gnome-session`  shold be the last command, and running in foreground. Your `.xinitrc` should be

```
 xclock &
 exec gnome-session
```

Comment: I don't want xclock running at all. If I just have `exec gnome-session` I get the freezing issue I am speaking of. The only way to make it work is to have some other application run in the foreground; like `exec xclock`.